# Showing name and saving id in symfony dropdown

Tags: symfony

I want to show the 'name' of my departments as a dropdown to my users and when they choose one, save its 'id' into the database. How can i do that? Below is my code. Currentlt its showing id and saving id.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('adress')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('area')
        ->add('departments', 'entity', array(
        'empty_value' => '',
            'class' => 'YdyaHospitalBundle:Department',
            'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC'); },
            'property' => 'id',
            'multiple' =>false,
            'expanded' =>true,
))
        ;
    }
```

Update

My controller action:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Hospitals entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="hospitals_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("YdyaHospitalBundle:Hospitals:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new Hospitals();


    $form = $this->createForm(new HospitalsType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('hospitals_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Hospitals entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="hospitals_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Hospitals();

    $form   = $this->createForm(new HospitalsType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement a `__toString()` for your entity, or specify the property to display with:

```
->add('departments', 'entity', array(
    'empty_value' => '',
    'class' => 'YdyaHospitalBundle:Department',
    'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC'); },
    // 'property' => 'id', --> Remove this
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'property' => 'name' // Property used to display the entity
))
```

In your Controller you'll still be able to save your entity or the id of your entity to the db.

See documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property

Comment: ThankYou.Can you please explain it some more clearly? Setting the property as name throws me an error bcoz the database expects an integer.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you handle the submitted form and insert the data into your db?

Comment: @Syjin..I am very new to symfony.I still can not understand its work flow. Still, I have posted the code. Please see the updated question

Comment: @DencyGB Your code looks fine. Can you please post the error message?

Comment: You were right syjin..Implemented the to__string method and it works fine!